# Python Pyxl: Writing to workbook and saving

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm practicing on pyxl packadge and I'm trying to write in a excel file via Python. I'm creating a new sheet and then saving it, but the excel workbook is not changing at all. I'm getting an error in the console. Any idead how to fix the error? I'm using Spyder (Python 3.6)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/z000xxx/.spyder-py3'

```
import os
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']


wb.create_sheet('Sheet4')
print(wb.sheetnames)
wb.save('C:/Users/z000xxx/.spyder-py3')
```

Comment: That `'C:/Users/z000479/.spyder-py3'` looks like a directory name, not a filename.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common error in windows when your file path is not valid, change your path to look something like this:

```
wb.save('C:\\Users\\z000479\\.spyder-py3\\yourFile.xlsx')
```

Comment: I think it also throw this error (Errno 13) if you have the file open already too